# uwp GetcurrentPoint image

Tags: pointers, uwp, move

I am writing a code that move an image. it works.
I need the absolute x, y after the moving
how ca I get them ?
thank you 
my code gives me only the relative points. :

```
 private static void MyImage_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Pointer ptr = e.Pointer;
        if (ptr.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
        {
            // To get mouse state, we need extended pointer details.
            // We get the pointer info through the getCurrentPoint method
            // of the event argument. 
            Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint ptrPt = e.GetCurrentPoint(micky.MyImage);
            var transform = (micky.MyImage.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform);
            double imagex = e.GetCurrentPoint(micky.MyImage).Position.X;
            double imageY = e.GetCurrentPoint(micky.MyImage).Position.Y;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do. If you just want to get the image's absolute position. You could use `TransformToVisual` and `TransformPoint` method.

```
<Image x:Name="pic" Source="Assets/1.jpg"/>
```

```cs
var trans = pic.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
Point position = trans.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
```

But I checked your code, I guess you want to move your image. If so, using `Manipulation` event should meet your target.

```
<Image x:Name="pic" Source="Assets/1.jpg" ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationDelta="Image_ManipulationDelta" Height="100" Width="200">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransform"></TranslateTransform>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

```cs
private void Image_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        translateTransform.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        translateTransform.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Manipulation: X: " + translateTransform.X + ", Y: " + translateTransform.Y);
    }
```